# In GEF how to avoid overlapping links on each other and on other GEF elements

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef, eclipse-emf-ecore

On a GEF canvas I have number or figures to represent a flow charts. Now these flow charts are coupled and we have multiple flowcharts. Now the issue is each gef figure has 1 or more links that connect between 2 elements. As number of elements are more, the links are crossing each other as well as links are crossing other GEF elements. This creates a messy picture /diagram.

I want to avoid such thing , meaning  I want to make sure that links do not cross each other as well as links do not cross any other element . Is there any way I can do it in GEF ? Any idea....

In GEF , I see there is something called bendpoints, but for that I assume, we need to put some logic so that they do not overlap. Is there readymade/auto logic avilable that we can use to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.draw2d.ShortestPathConnectionRouter` router for the links.
Please see GEF's Flow example plugin. It has the behaviour you'd like implemented. (`org.eclipse.gef.examples.flow` plug-in project)

Comment: Thanks, we have used along with algorithm that does same.